# Joint Probability Decomposition for Conditional Independence

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

How do I express in a probability formula, B is independent of C given A?
In particular, I would like to write a decomposition of P(A,B,C) using this information.

Comment: One way could be $\mathbb P(B \mid A,C)=\mathbb P(B \mid A)$.  Another could be $\mathbb P(B,C\mid A)= \mathbb P(B\mid A)\mathbb P(C\mid A)$.  Both would lead to $\mathbb P(A,B, C)= \mathbb P(B\mid A)\mathbb P(C\mid A)\mathbb P(A)$

Comment: Thanks very much!!

Comment: @Henry, do you mind showing how you got P(A,B|C) = P(A|C)P(B|C) ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "$\mathbb P(B,C\mid A)= \mathbb P(B\mid A)\mathbb P(C\mid A)$" is one way of defining $B$ and $C$ being conditionally independent given $A$